# Increase Value of Array Index?

Tags: php

I was Do some Testing on Arrays , but I saw something in my code :

```
    $arr = array();
    $arr[0]++;
    echo $arr[0];
```

output = 1 ;

Why is index[0] value is 1 ?

From my code above I don't do an assignment like

```
$arr[0] = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is due to loose types in PHP.

```
null == false == 0
```

this means that `$arr[0]` (`null` before the ++) is loosely equal to 0. So null (or 0) + 1 = 1.

Comment: The value is never `false` though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson amended :D

Answer (score 3):

Because it interprets as `$arr[0] = $arr[0] + 1 ;`. If you try with `var_dump($arr[0])`, then you will see that `var_dump($arr[0]);` returns `NULL` so `NULL + 1` is equal to 1(converts **NULL to 0** internally) that's why it returns `1` at the end.

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = $arr[0] + 1 ;
echo $arr[0];
```

Also you should see a **Notice** like

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: ah, I assumed it's because $arr[0] is null/false, so +1 to "0" (false) becomes 1!

Comment: thanks alot , can you give me a source for this ? 
because in php we used to do like this $arr +=1 ; and so ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr[0]++;
```

That expression is execured as:

```
$arr[0] = $arr[0] + 1;
```

but your array doesn't contain an element with zero index. That element isn't instantiated and that value is `null`. That expression can be written as:

```
$arr[0] = null + 1;
```

`null` value converted to integer and have 0 value automaticaly and the expression is executed as

```
$arr[0] = 0 + 1;
```

Comment: I was also saying that sir :) earlier

Answer (score 1):

Not that it really matters, because the effect is the same, but there is no type juggling before the increment operation. Incrementing an undefined value directly results in 1. It is not converted to zero and then incremented.

The PHP manual explains this behavior. First, [`null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php):

> The special NULL value represents a variable with no value. NULL is the only possible value of type null.
>
> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant NULL.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been unset().

Next, [Incrementing/Decrementing operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> Note: The increment/decrement operators only affect numbers and strings. Arrays, objects, booleans and resources are not affected. **Decrementing NULL values has no effect too, but incrementing them results in 1**.

So, `$arr[0]` is `null` because it has not been set to any value yet.
And incrementing `null` results in 1.

Comment: would this mean all of our answers are *technically* wrong? o.O

Comment: @treyBake Yes and no. Of course null is loosely equal to zero. But I don't think that type conversion occurs before the increment operation, so _technically_ I think they are slightly off in that respect. But like I said, not that it really matters.

Comment: I don't know if it would be possible to test it as a PHP developer because it happens internally during one statement, so you wouldn't be able to see it in xdebug. I just looked at the PHP source after reading the manual

Comment: I think this is where it happens: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_operators.c#L2436 I'm definitely not a C programmer so I could be mistaken.

Comment: ZVAL_LONG is a macro for setting a value and type at the same time. It mentions macros like that at the end of that book page you linked. But really as PHP devs I think we shouldn't worry much about how it's implemented internally. The external effect is the same regardless of that, so my answer is mostly just trivia

Comment: Ahhh I see, I read that to mean, IS_NULL, set LONG value 1 -> but I guess that doesn't necessarily mean conversion - will rm above comments as yeah, from the PHP-side, this I guess isn't needed, but definitely interesting :p

Answer (score 0):

Use 1 of 3 examples:

```php
<?php
$arr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr)+1; $i++){
    $arr[$i] = $i+1;
}

echo $arr[0]; //1
?>
```

```php
<?php
 $arr = array('0');
 $arr[0]++;
 echo $arr[0]; //1
?>
```

```php
<?php
$arr[0] = 0;

echo $arr[0]++; //1
?>
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does, and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and more likely to attract upvotes.